# How to prevent Windows Media Player from popping up every time I add a new MP3?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

Title says it all.  Every time I add a new MP3 to a subfolder of My Music, Media Player pops up a window on top of what I'm working on.  It's really annoying when downloading music in the background.  I want the files to be added to its library, but there's no need to open the UI in my face all the time.  How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: What exactly does the window say? A screen shot would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still running XP and in that version you can disable it by changing what folders are monitored or watched. Changes can be made to that by going to the Library tab of the dialog box that appears after selecting the **Tools** | **Options...** sub-menu.

[image]